# Interface with constructor in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am start to develop an application in ASP.NET Core MVC, and I am going to implement file operations (upload, delete, copy files etc). For that I wrote some methods in `FileHelperMethod` class

```
public class FileHelperMethod
{
        private string Url = "";
        private string virtualpath = "";
        private readonly string uploadfolderpath = string.Empty;
        private readonly string tempuploadRootFolder = string.Empty;
        private readonly string subfolderstructure = string.Empty;
        private readonly HttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;
        private readonly HostingPaths hostingPath;
        
        public  FileHelperMethod()
        {
            httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
            hostingPath = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IOptions<HostingPaths>>().Value;
            webHostEnvironment = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();

            this.Url = webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath+"/";// hostingPath.FileHosting.Url + "/";
            this.virtualpath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostingPath.FileHosting.VirtualPath) ? "" : hostingPath.FileHosting.VirtualPath + "/";
            tempuploadRootFolder = this.Url + this.virtualpath;
        }

        public FileHelperMethod(FileContainers fileContainer) : this()
        {
            this.uploadfolderpath = fileContainer.ToString() + "/";
            tempuploadRootFolder = this.tempuploadRootFolder + this.uploadfolderpath;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// when need a a dynamic folder Structure ,like user wise files then may be we want to
        /// store user's file in a folder by User's id. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="SubfolderStructure"></param>
        public FileHelperMethod(FileContainers fileContainer,string SubfolderStructure):this(fileContainer)
        {
            this.subfolderstructure = SubfolderStructure + "/";
            tempuploadRootFolder = this.tempuploadRootFolder + SubfolderStructure + "/";
        }

        public UploadedFileDetails UploadFile(IFormFile _file)
        {
            //...............
        }
}
```

This class expects some parameters in constructor for building final upload path for a file.

As shown here, I create an instance of the class:

```
 var dropZoneHelperMethod = new FileHelperMethod(FileContainers.Template);
```

Currently we are storing files on our own servers, so these methods are working fine, but in the near future, we are planning to move to AWS or Azure. For that I need to write an interface with basic functionalities. But I am facing a problem with the constructor. We cannot have a constructor in an interface, and without constructor we can't build the file upload location dynamically from code at runtime.

Please help to overcome this problem.

Comment: You can have a construcdtor in some class, that implements the interface. What's the problem with that approach?

Comment: You also need a class that *implements* that interface. And that can have a ctor

Comment: If you want to ensure all the classes implementing the interface handle things the same way, you could always define a method something like `public void Initialize(.....)` on the interface; it's not quite a compelling and strong as the constructor - but depending on what you're trying to do with it, it might be good enough

Comment: Don't think about the future, think about now as the rule YAGNI says.